# How can I display dateUpdated for the most recent updated entry in a category?

Tags: templating, entries, updating

I would like to display the date that the site was last updated. This date is the same as the last entry added to a specific category. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [order](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order) entries by `dateUpdated` in descending order and then get the first entry. You would use that entries `dateUpdated` field to show when the site was last updated.

```
{% set entry = craft.entries.order( 'dateUpdated desc' ).first() %}
{{ entry.dateUpdated }}
```

Comment: As a side note to this answer when I needed to do this I had to change order to: .order('elements.dateUpdated desc')